# How ERC1155 can behave like ERC20?

Tags: solidity, erc-1155

As we say that ERC1155 can define both fungible and NFTs, how exactly is that implemented? The ERC has all the functions like an ERC721, and also it attaches a URI with all of the tokens, but ERC20 tokens don't have URIs, they have decimals.

I am confused how to define both types of tokens. Like having different types of NFTs as well as different types of ERC20 tokens.